# How to keep chunks loaded in minecraft 1.13.2 without /forceload

Tags: minecraft-commands

Title asks it all, any ideas???

Teleporting entities to unloaded chunks aint working anymore...

Comment: Why do you need chunks to stay loaded?

Comment: Because its for a TARDIS map and I can't always load the chunks

Comment: That doesn't actually answer my question.  I don't know what a TARDIS map is.  You're going to get much better answers if you fully explain what the problem is you're facing.

Answer (score 4):

Redstone is the easiest way to keep chunks loaded. Basically, with the right timing, you can create devices that update the "chunk register" regularly enough to keep that area loaded, due to regular activity in that specific area.

Since the Spawn Chunks are never *unloaded*, creating a redstone chain from the spawn chunks to your desired location will ensure that those chunks are never unloaded.

This video by Gnembon goes into the mechanics of it in far greater detail.

Comment: Can't do that because this is a TARDIS map so the chunks are generated by the player, not set chunks.